# How to get DataType in Apex

Tags: apex, data-types

I am using utility class methods which are called in test class to populate all fields of say XYZ object.But i have a field in XYZ object which is formula field. As it is read only i would not want to populate it since it gives me an exception for populating read only field. 
I tried using below method for DescribeFieldResult object,

```
public Schema.DisplayType getType()
```

Though above works if there is no formula field but doesnt work in my case as it depends on the return type(Formula field may have any type Text/Date/Currency). I am a newbie. Hope i will get a better guidance on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you trying to populate the formula field? It's populated at runtime wherever it needs to be.

Comment: I had made it dynamic. I was populating all fields(by getting field list Sobject.getDescribe().fields.getMap()) and i needed a way to skip formula field. Anyhow @Stuart's code worked for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may want something like below:

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType>     globalDescribe          = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
Schema.SObjectType                  objectType              = globalDescribe.get(YOUR_OBJECT_NAME);
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult        objectDescribeResult    = objectType.getDescribe();

Map<String, Schema.SObjectField>    objectFieldMap          = objectDescribeResult.fields.getMap();
Schema.SObjectField                 objectField             = objectFieldMap.get(YOUR_FIELD_NAME);
Schema.DescribeFieldResult          fieldDescription        = objectField.getDescribe();

//Alternatively...
//Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldDescription = YOUR_OBJECT_NAME.YOUR_FIELD_NAME.getDescribe();   

if(!fieldDescription.IsCalculated())
{
      // yourObject - this is an instance of YOUR_OBJECT_NAME
      yourObject.YOUR_FIELD_NAME = 123;
}
else
{
    // do nothing - its a formula field
}
```

The important part is the DescribeFieldResult object
From the docs…
IsCalculated - Returns true if the field is a custom formula field, false otherwise. Note that custom formula fields are always read-only.

[Schema.DescribeFieldResult Docs Link](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeFieldResult_isCalculated)